# alicloud_cs_managed_kubernetes vs alicloud_cs_kubernetes on terraform

Tags: terraform

So on Alibaba Cloud module in terraform and found identic resource:

```
alicloud_cs_managed_kubernetes
```

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/alicloud/r/cs_managed_kubernetes.html

```
alicloud_cs_kubernetes
```

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/alicloud/r/cs_kubernetes.html

what is the different of that? i cannot differentiate that two resource

Answer (score 1):

biggest difference is,

Managed kubernetes cluster, that means you can't control kubernetes master.

kubernetes cluster, you need create master as well.

```
  master_instance_types = ["ecs.n4.small"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifically speaking the differences between alicloud_cs_managed_kubernetes vs alicloud_cs_kubernetes on Terraform are can be addressed detailly with the help of parameter reference provided on official documentation.

But, the major difference between Kubernetes and Managed Kubernetes is

> You don't need to manage the master node in Managed Kubernetes